# Do you know how I can tell why I have two hot wires?

Tags: electrical, wiring, recessed-lighting

All the outlets in the house are working and have connected neutral wires. However one unit has a both hot and neutral wires reading hot. And the light isn’t working. Can’t figure out why or where a neutral isn’t connected. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

You have the right idea that a neutral may be open.
This is common with back stabs (the push in connectors on outlets)   I start closest to the service panel checking receptacles. Looking for the first one on that circuit  that gives the problem. Check that and if it is good back up to the last working one if things start working and there were backstabs they will fail again. Many of us never use backstabs and recommend the screw terminals or replace with new receptacles. There can also be a broken wire or a loose wire in a wire nut but the most common failure is the backstab from no visible damage and they start working when checked to the wire burned off and part of the receptacle melted.
So find the first failed one or the last working one and it will be in one of those 2 locations.

Comment: Get rid of the backstabs even if they're not the immediate problem.+